# How to draw an animated logo using dart flutter as a splash screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a dynamic logo using as a splash screen using dart flutter as the below image

[image: Logo]

So as the previous image this shield logo there's a way to create it dynamically using `dart-flutter` as to able to animate it easily as dragable those small squares in the shield logo...

There's a tutorial or docs related to this case could help me...

I hope this would be clear enough..

Answer (score 1):

If there is no user interaction then you could use
[Lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) animation or else if you want to have a user interaction with the animation to it then you could do like

- ColorFiltered with the position
- Update the state of the position from drag/click position